# Java scanner in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I want to write a function which returns true if the first character of the input is a questionmark and false if it isn't

```
boolean volgendeCharIsVraagteken(Scanner in){
        if(in.next().charAt(0) == '?'){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

However, it reads away the first word and then checks for a quastionmark.
I want to only check and not read away the questionmark yet.
How can I make that happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "read away the question mark"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "peek" the next element on a Java Scanner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288643/how-do-i-peek-the-next-element-on-a-java-scanner)

Comment: Use hasNext() rather than next().

Comment: It removes it from the scanner, so if my input is ? 123 and after the boolean I print the entire scanner input it only prints 123 without the ?

Comment: @JBNizet That wouldn't help him since he still needs to somehow access the word.

Comment: @tortilla If you need to reuse the content, store it. The `Iterator` interace was designed to do exactly what it is doing here. By the way, you can shorten the method to simply `return in.next().charAt(0) == '?';`.

Comment: @IngoBürk: hasNext() takes a regex pattern as argument. So it can tst if it has a next element starting with a qiuestion mark, using the appropriate regexp.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that (it's not contained in the `Iterator` interface itself). Always something new to learn, thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet You should put this into an answer. Seems like the best choice to me.

Comment: @JBNizet Good solution, is there anyway that the hasNext can also check the first character of an entire line. So if the input is 1234 it has to check if the first character is 1. And if so print it. But I want it to print 1234 and not 234

Comment: @tortilla you would have to temporary change scanners delimiter to line separator (you can get it with `System.lineSeparator()`) use `hasNext(yourPatter)` and then if you need change back delimiter to its default version `"\\p{javaWhitespace}+"`.