# How to check nextInt from Scanner without consuming the int itself

Tags: java, conditional-statements, java.util.scanner

What I am attempting to do is verify user input of an integer between 0-136, while also making sure that the input IS in fact an integer. I can't figure out a good way to do so, as using nextInt in the conditional consumes the int, and you can't compare hasNextInt to integers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public static int retrieveYearsBack() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Retrieve yearsBack
    System.out.println("How many years back would you like to search? (Enter only positive whole numbers less than 136)");
    while (!input.hasNextInt([0-136]) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a positive whole number less than 136 only.");
        input.next();
    }
    return input.nextInt();
}
```

I have also tried:

```
int myYears = -1;
int tempValue = 0;
while (!input.hasNextInt() || (myYears < 0 || myYears > 136)) {
  if (input.hasNextInt())
      tempValue = input.nextInt();
  if (tempValue > 0 && tempValue < 136)
      myYears = tempValue;
  else {
      System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a positive whole number less than 136 only.");
      input.next();
  }
}
```

This try gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288643/how-do-i-peek-the-next-element-on-a-java-scanner) may help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe that you do need the `input.next()` call despite what Vivin says. If you can't read an integer from the next line of stdin then you will end up in an infinite loop. Furthermore, you should handle the case where you run out of lines of stdin to process, which can happen where your application's input is from a pipe instead of an interactive session.

In a more verbose style, this might look something like:

```
public static int retrieveYearsBack() throws Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int years = input.nextInt();
            if (0 <= years && years <= 136) {
                return years;
            }
        } else {
            input.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter a positive whole number less than 136.");
    }

    throw new Exception("Standard in was closed whilst awaiting a valid input from the user.");
}
```

Comment: You're right, Tom -- I've removed the calls to input.close(). I was previously thinking that it could tidy up the Scanner, not the underlying stream it uses.